# How can I conditionally render this component based on whether or not there is data in localstorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-rendering

I want MyList to render whatever is in localStorage (works great), however when there is nothing in local storage and I render the component, it renders empty. I would like to have a placeholder there for when that occurs. How can I best do that?

```
const MyList = ({setDrinks}) => {
    const setMyList = () => {
        let parsedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favoriteDrinks'))
        setDrinks(parsedData)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button className="my-list" onClick={setMyList}>My List</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyList
```

Comment: Try assigning some value to parsedData when it becomes null like this. `let parsedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favoriteDrinks')) || <value you'd like to set as placeholder>`. Or you can also put it inside your JSON.parse like this. `let parsedData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favoriteDrinks') || <default value>)`

Comment: Putting it in the parse breaks the button, putting it outside of the parse does nothing. Do I need to create new state??

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a random placeholder if your `localStorage` does not have data. Here's a minimal solution:

```
const MyList = ({setDrinks}) => {
    const setMyList = () => {
        const myDrinks = localStorage.getItem('favoriteDrinks');
        if (!myDrinks) {
            setDrinks({ message: "No drinks found!" });
            return;
        } 
        let parsedData = JSON.parse(myDrinks);
        setDrinks(parsedData);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <button className="my-list" onClick={setMyList}>My List</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MyList
```